# Aggregating method used by BaggingClassifier and BaggingRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, bagging

What aggregating method is used by BaggingClassifier and BaggingRegressor in sklearn? Do they use soft voting or hard voting or averaging? The sklearn docs don't seem to clearly specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. BaggingClassifier uses soft voting (averaging probabilities) if the base estimator has a predict_proba() method and hard voting otherwise. On the other hand, BaggingRegressor uses averaging. Makes sense.